# como consultar datos guardados como 1 de un checkbox y mostrarlos en lista en formato checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, tablas

buen día, tengo una tabla con varios checkbox, el value="1" en todos y en mysql se muestra como 1, al momento de consultarlo se me muestran los datos con el número 1 pero quisiera que se mostraran en formato checkbox

```html
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'BD')or die(mysqli_error($mysql));

$OP=$_POST['OP'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM desbarbe WHERE OP='$OP' ORDER BY id DESC";
$execute = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute)){

    echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['db1'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db2'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db3'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db4'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db5'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db6'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db9'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db8'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['db7'] . "</td>
    </tr>  ";
}

?>
```

Con el codigo anterior me muestra esto al registrar los datos con el botón guardar se enlista automáticamente debajo de la tabla pero se muestra con el número 1 me gustaría que se muestre en formato check (se utiliza Javascript para el botón guardar)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba asi:

```php
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'BD') or die(mysqli_error($mysql));

$OP = $_POST['OP'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM desbarbe WHERE OP='$OP' ORDER BY id DESC";
$execute = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

function checked($valor) {
    return $valor ? 'checked' : '';
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute)) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($row["db1"]) . ' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($row["db2"]) . ' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($row["db3"]) . ' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($row["db4"]) . ' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($row["db5"]) . ' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($row["db6"]) . ' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ' . checked($row["db7"]) . ' /></td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Ya comentaras

Comment: Perfecto, me funciono muy bien muestra los checkbox tal como quería muchass gracias